# Passport expiration for Greek national visiting New York

Tags: usa, esta, greek-citizens

I would like to visit New York for vacation at the end of January 2019 for a week. I will depart from Cyprus (I am a permanent resident but do not have Cypriot travel documents), and I will have a connection in the UK. My Greek passport expires at the end of March 2019 (so my passport's validity will be approximately 2 months at the time of departure). Will I need to be issued a new passport?

As I have checked online, most probably as Greek passport holder I can obtain an ESTA, and so passport should be valid , and not expired, for the duration of the intended stay. But is there anyone out there that can confirm that for sure?

Answer (score 4):

You can find documents confirming that your passport needs only to be valid for the duration of the stay on the USCBP webpage.  (USCBP is the United States Customs and Border Protection agency.)

[The default requirement is that foreign nationals must present a passport with six months of validity:](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/572/kw/passport%20validity%20to%20enter%20USA/session/L3RpbWUvMTUzNDc5Mjk1OS9zaWQvcE1TKmxKVW4%3D)

> Visitors traveling to the U.S. are required to be in possession of passports that are valid for six months beyond the period of their intended stay in the U.S.

[However, passport holders from certain countries are exempt from this requirement:](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2017-Dec/Six-Month%20Club%20Update122017.pdf) (PDF)

> Citizens of the countries listed below are exempt the six-month rule and need only have a passport valid for their intended period of stay.
>
> Andorra,
> Angola,
> Antigua and Barbuda,
> Argentina,
> Armenia,
> Aruba,
> Australia,
> Austria,
> Bahamas, Barbados,
> Belgium,
> Belize,
> Bermuda,
> Bolivia, Bosnia-Herzegovina, Brazil,
> Bulgaria,
> Burma,
> Canada,
> Chile,
> Colombia,
> Costa Rica,
> Cote d’Ivoire, Croatia,
> Cyprus,
> Czech Republic, Denmark,
> Dominica, Dominican Republic, Egypt,
> El Salvador,
> Estonia,
> Ethiopia,
> Fiji,
> Finland, France,
> Gabon, Georgia, Germany, ***Greece,*** Grenada, Guatemala, Guinea, Guyana,
> Haiti,
> Hong Kong (Certificates of Identity and Passports), Hungary, Iceland,
> India, Indonesia, Ireland,
> Israel,
> Italy,
> Jamaica, Japan, Kosovo, Latvia, Lebanon, Libya, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg,
> Macau, Macedonia, Madagascar, Maldives, Malaysia,
> Malta,
> Mauritania, Mauritius, Mexico,
> Monaco, Mongolia, Montenegro, Mozambique, Nepal, Netherlands,
> New Zealand, Nicaragua, Nigeria,
> Norway,
> Pakistan,
> Palau,
> Panama,
> Papua New Guinea, Paraguay,
> Peru, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, Qatar, Romania, Russia,
> San Marino,
> Saudi Arabia, Serbia, Seychelles, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, South Africa, South Korea, Spain,
> Sri Lanka,
> St. Kitts and Nevis, St. Lucia,
> St. Vincent and The Grenadines,
> Suriname,
> Sweden,
> Switzerland,
> Taiwan,
> Thailand,
> Trinidad and Tobago, Tunisia,
> Turkey,
> Tuvalu,
> Ukraine,
> United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom, Uruguay,
> Uzbekistan,
> Vatican (Holy See), Venezuela,
> Zimbabwe

Amusingly, there are ~130 countries listed here, and only 195 countries in the world, meaning that there are more "exceptions" than there are countries for which the six-month rule applies.